# Getting data from a submitted form and organizing on sheets

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Edit: Adding a picture of my spreadsheet.
[spreadsheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsltO.png)
Let's say the data for the 3rd submission C3-F3 belongs in the Ink sheet and G3 - J3 belongs in the colors category. I don't know how to collect the submitted data range so that I'm not manually typing it, and copy it to a new row in the category sheet.

I have a bunch or responses from a survey on the first sheet (I named it response data), but I want to organize the data better and sort the responses into the corresponding sheets. I'm able to copy a specific row from the response and paste it into a specific row on a sheet that I specify, but I don't know how to get the data range for the data that was just submitted.

```
function onOpen() {
 try {
   const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const menuItems = [
     {name: 'Organize...', functionName: 'organize_'},
   ];
   spreadsheet.addMenu('Organize', menuItems);
 } catch (e) {
   // TODO (Developer) - Handle Exception
   Logger.log('Failed with error: %s' + e.error);
 }
}

function organize_() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var responseData = ss.getSheetByName("Response Data");
 responseData.activate();

 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 

 var result1 = ui.alert(
     'Refresh Spreadsheet?',
     ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

 // Process the user's response.
 if (result1 == ui.Button.OK) { // User clicked "OK".
   
   var result2 = ui.prompt(
     'Test Type',
     ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

     var text = result2.getResponseText();
  var  sampleType =ss.getSheetByName (text)
 var newRow = responseData.getRange("A2:F2") //How do I get the data for the row that was just submitted?
 newRow.copyTo(sampleType.getRange("A2:F2")) // copy to new row

 
 }else if (result1 == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
   // User clicked "Cancel".
   ui.alert('nvm.');
 } else if (result1 == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
   // User clicked X in the title bar.
   ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
 }

}
```

Comment: The data for the submitted row is in the event object of the submission  trigger.  All submissions start with a time stamp which is in column one and the each questions  answer follows in the remaining columns all of that is in "values" if e is the parameter you chose to be populated by the event object the e.values[0] is the timestamp and all of the data that is submitted is in e.values.  You can also refer to the data by by title if you wish to use namedValues then in would be e.namedValues(title)[0].

Comment: So you really don't need to know the range but just in caused you wish to have it, the sheet is e.range.getSheet() and the row is e.range.getRow().

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. Let's say that for my spreadsheet  columns A and B are Timestamp and Names ,  columns A-F are for category 1, columns G-J are category 2, and K-N are category 3. I have sheets for each of the categories.  When I hit organize on my menu I want the timestamp, name, and data from the correct category to be copied into it's respective sheet.

Comment: Only columnA is timestamp in my forms.

Comment: yeah column A is the timestamp in my forms too and column B is the names

Comment: Then please provide more amplifiying information in your secondary question